# Error Causing APK to crash for libplayer.so

Tags: java, android

I use buildbox to make games and I am facing the same issue. While I wait for them to fix it, I was wondering if someone on here can help me out. The App crashes the moment I try to launch it and the error I am getting from debug mode is basically "couldn't find libplayer.so"

Would be great if someone on here can help resolve it. Pasting the logcat below for reference

Hi Sean, so I have tried removing both Ads and firebase from my project and my app was still crashing on launch, both on the emulator and on my Galaxy S8+. So I created a couple of test projects using just the templates provided in BB and the new Apps are crashing as well. Linking you the BBDOC file and the Android Project along with pasting the logcat below. PLEASE HELP! As far as I can understand, it is a Buildbox issue. I am currently using version 2.3.7.

```
2018-12-07 12:03:44.778 11638-11638/com.companyname.gamename E/AndroidRuntime:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main    Process: com.companyname.gamename, PID: 11638
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[
[zip file "/data/app/com.companyname.gamename-PSsNelEnqpOX4JAFmool9w==/base.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.companyname.gamename-PSsNelEnqpOX4JAFmool9w==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]]
couldn't find "libplayer.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1011)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1657)
        at com.companyname.gamename.PTPlayer.<clinit>(PTPlayer.java:123)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1173)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2708)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Have you got any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

The player.so library  is missing from your lib folder and please make sure you add it for all required architecture.